# Relate a checkbox with another input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to do something. I have the following code snippet:

```
echo "<form class='additionals'>";               
foreach($connection->query($sql2) as $additional)
{
    echo "<input class='additional-checkbox' type='checkbox' name='additional_id'
            value='{$additional['additional_id']}'/>
        {$additional['additional_name']} - &#36;{$additional['additional_price']}
        <input type='number' name='additional_quantity' value='1' min='1' max='5'/>
        <br/>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

What I need is when any checkbox with name `additional_id` is not checked, the input in front of it with name `additional_quantity` related to their quantity is disabled and vice-versa. But I do not know how to do this, even more because I need to use `foreach`. Can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Do your checkboxes always start out unchecked?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes. I think when the page loads I need a code that disables the quantity inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need:

- Note that I gave the checkboxes the class `enable`
- I have also added the `disabled` property to the actual html inputs, you'll need to add this in your php code
- I also gave each input a unique `name` If you're allowing multiple fields and will be submitting the form, they will all need unique names

```js
$('.enable').change(function(){
     var set =  $(this).is(':checked') ? false : true;      // ternary operator to test if the changed checkbox is now checked
     $(this).nextAll('input').first().attr('disabled',set); // find the next input and set it's disabled property according to the previous check  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='additionals'>
  <input class='additional-checkbox enable' type='checkbox' name='additional_id1' value='somevalue' />somevalue
  <input type='number' name='additional_quantity1' value='1' min='1' max='5' disabled/>
  <br/>
  <input class='additional-checkbox enable' type='checkbox' name='additional_id2' value='somevalue' />somevalue
  <input type='number' name='additional_quantity2' value='1' min='1' max='5' disabled/>
  <br/>
  <input class='additional-checkbox enable' type='checkbox' name='additional_id3' value='somevalue' />somevalue
  <input type='number' name='additional_quantity3' value='1' min='1' max='5' disabled/>
  <br/>
  <input class='additional-checkbox enable' type='checkbox' name='additional_id4' value='somevalue' />somevalue
  <input type='number' name='additional_quantity4' value='1' min='1' max='5' disabled/>
  <br/>
  <input class='additional-checkbox enable' type='checkbox' name='additional_id5' value='somevalue' />somevalue
  <input type='number' name='additional_quantity5' value='1' min='1' max='5' disabled/>
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I don't need to use different names for the checkboxes because I'm using `.serialize form`. I needed to disable the quantity inputs of unselected checkboxes because when serializing the form, the quantity inputs of unselected checkboxes were also included. 
The only problem I found with your code was that the quantity inputs are disabled only when I click. They need to be disabled when the page loads too.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I also added the property `disabled` to the inputs,this way they start disabled and are only enabled if you click the preceding checkbox

Comment: I saw it. Strange, in my code they are enabled when the page loads. Maybe because I need to use an unique name for each of them?

Comment: That shouldnt cause that

Comment: Did you set `disabled` in your php code that echos the elements, like  `echo " ......   <input type='number' name='additional_quantity' value='1' min='1' max='5' disabled/>"`?

Comment: Checked this right now. Worked like a charm! 
I just have to thank you, I was trying to do this all day! A great hug!